# delay with serving asp.net mvc application - precompile?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, compilation

I am using discount asp to host an asp.net mvc 2.0 application. Unfortunately, every time I go to a page on the site, there is a long delay of 10-15 seconds. I am assuming that this is because the apppool is getting unloaded due to inactivity and once a request is received, the app has to reload which takes some time. How do I avoid this. Can I precompile an mvc application so this does not happen? or is there another way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a new feature in IIS 7.5 and ASP.NET 4.0 that allows you to [auto-start applications](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx). If you are using IIS 6 you could uncheck the `Shutdown worker process after being idle for` in the properties of the application pool but the first request when the server restarts will still be slow and AFAIK there's not much you can do about it:

[alt text http://www.issueview.com/images/DefaultAppPoolProperties.PNG](http://www.issueview.com/images/DefaultAppPoolProperties.PNG)